# Foundry Logging no longer working for contracts in lib folder?

Tags: foundry, logs, library, forge, fuzz-test

My fuzz tests are calling Smart Contracts in my `lib/` folder.
In these tests, I'm trying to log variables, but nothing is logged.

**Yes, I'm using -vv.**
I even increased verbosity (all the way up to `-vvvvv`) but the  problem remains.

I've tried:

- console.log()
- console2.log()
- emit()
- emit_string()

But nothing works:
[image]

I've noticed that it still **works for contracts in my `src/` folder, but not for contracts in my `lib/` folder.**

So could it be a conflict between these two?
[image]

My forge version:
`forge 0.2.0 (fd87629 2024-02-14T00:19:19.704338000Z)`

This used to work, but now it doesn't work anymore.
Help?

Answer (score 0):

is the depth of the folder correct on the imports? the ' ../ '.
sometimes the file you are trying to import is out of reach.

try adding more " ../ " and also if theres another directory (like "src") in between add it.

```
import {console} from "../../../forge-std/src/console.log"
```

It could be because of conflict between the 2 folders but I have never had that problem so I don't think so.